# Pushing element in a cloned object of state adds value to the state attribute instantaneously

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to publish an updated object but not trying to change the state through the following code in react:

```
addPlaceToSearch = (place) => {
    if (place != this.state.search_text) {
      var search = $.extend({}, this.state.search);
      if (!search.added_places.includes(place)) {
        search.added_places.push(place);
        PubSub.publish('searchUpdated', search);
      }
    }
  }
```

Thus, I am using `$.extend({}, this.state.search)` to clone the object into another variable, modify that particular variable and then publish it. But when I execute the `line 5`, and I put a breakpoint on `line 6`, I can see that the `this.state.search` is also changed with `place` being pushed in it's `added_places` key (which I do not want). How is this happening? And how can I prevent it? I have also tried `Object.assign({}, this.state.search)` instead of `$.extend({}, this.state.search)`.

**EDIT**

I even tried the most trivial solution, here it is:

```
addPlaceToSearch = (place) => {
    if (place != this.state.search_text) {
      if (!this.state.search.added_places.includes(place)) {
        var xyz = {};
        for (var key in this.state.search) {
          xyz[key] = this.state.search[key];
        }
        xyz.added_places.push(place);
        PubSub.publish('searchUpdated', xyz);
      }
    }
  }
```

Still, the `xyz.added_places.push(place)` line changes my this.state.search object too! Kindly help me out.

Comment: xyz[key] is still referencing this.state.search[key], if you use xyz[key] = Object.assign({}, this.state.search[key]) it should not keep the reference? Im not 100% sure if that is whats causing it though

Comment: `this.state.search[key]` are string/arrays/integer values, so `Object.assign({}, this.state.search[key])` is returning an empty object.

Comment: Oh, now i see what you are doing. Where do "place" come from ? is that stored in this.state? because that will still be bounded to state then. So you need to assign it using Object.assign

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after two hours of hard work, I figured out the solution by making a deep copy of the original array. I will read about the differences between shallow and deep copy as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/5159284), till then here is the solution:

```
var xyz = $.extend(true, {}, this.state.search);
xyz.added_places.push(place);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this better without jQuery using `Object.assign()`

```
var xyz = Object.assign({}, this.state.search)
xyz.added_places.push(place)
```

Comment: As already mentioned in my question, I had already tried this. But I think this method also does a shallow copy of the object, whereas I would require a recursive copy since my object includes an array.

Comment: This should help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone